# Implementing drag calendar with Flex and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, flex3

I want to implement an application in Flex/Rails in Background as I know these two languages but I'm fairly beginner with Flex and Intermediate-to-expert with Rails. My application will display a calendar like object by which there are say 5-day week or 7-day week or a month (30-days) and in each day there will be some data such as appointments or such. I want users to be able to drag left or right to get more days after or before the displayed week for example and I want the boxes to be filled with proper appointments data.

What is the best way to implmenet this in your opinion, mainly from Flex point of view? Any architectural tips from the Rails side?

Also, please tell me if you know something similar have been done before or book or articles that might have similar recipe.

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these [Object Handles](http://code.google.com/p/flex-object-handles/)

It allows you to put handles on your Flex objects (like your appointments) so that the user could easily move them from day to day or expand the time of the appointment.

Also, if I'm understanding what you are saying.  If you want to allow them to click and scroll left and right on the calendar between months, you should:

1. Listen for when the user's mouse gets clicked and held down
2. Once trapped in held down, use event to get whether user moves mouse left or right
3. Switch months based on how fast user scrolled left or right with mouse.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google on "flex calendar component" will reveal you a lot of results.

I can recommend you:

- http://flashenabledblog.com/2007/07/06/interactive-flex-calendar-componentwith-source-just-awesome/
- http://coolestflex.blogspot.com/2008/08/flex-calendar-component.html

I could add more, but i am not allowed to add more than 2 links :)

Comment: The second link is very similar to what I'm looking for as it has "timeline" component which is what I need. the problem it says on the website that it's "not even pre Alpha" and the trunk files dates back to 2007 so I doubt there is much development going there..Do you know of other ones similar (i.e. has timeline component and not just calendar)?

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.thetechlabs.com/tutorials/interfaces/create-a-dynamic-event-calendar-in-flex-builder-3-with-actionscript-30/) goes over how to build a flex calendar.  Once you have that, since you will have all of the source, just add the drag 'n drop behavior you need to it.

See the [Flex Quickstart on dnd](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/adding_drag_and_drop/) if you need more info on how to do drag and drop.

Comment: It's back up now... don't know why